# How to use FILE_MASK parameter in FM EPS2_GET_DIRECTORY_LISTING

Tags: abap

I am trying to filter files using `FILE_MASK` parameter in `EPS2_GET_DIRECTORY_LISTING` to reduce time searching all files in the folder (has thousands of files).

File mask I tried:

```
TK5_*20150811*
```

file name in the folder is;

> TK5_Invoic_828243P_**20150811**111946364.xml.asc

But it exports all files to DIR_LIST table, so nothing filtered.

But when I try with;

```
TK5_Invoic*20150811*
```

It works!

What I think is it works if I give first 10 characters as it is. But in my case I do not have first 10 characters always.

Can you give me an advice on using `FILE_MASK`?

Comment: Strange but this function module returns unexpected results for me. For example I see that there is a file with exe extension in the directory but when I use `FILE_MASK` `*.exe` it returns nothing. I happens on a Linux app server as well as on a Windows one.

Comment: I have just tried it with the exact file and exactly the same masks. It works correctly in both cases for me. Tested on Windows as well as on Linux, so the problem seems to be somewhere else.

Comment: I confirm too: both masks works for me. So your problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Haven’t tried, but this sounds plausible:
https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3470593

> The * wildcard may only be used at the end of the search string.
>   It is not specified, what a '*' matches to, when it is not the last non-space character in the FILE parameter value.